# How can I get type from object of array

Tags: typescript, types

```
type Item = {
  id: string;
  value: string;
};

const items: Readonly<Item>[] = [
  { id: 'id1', value: 'TODO1' },
  { id: 'id2', value: 'TODO2' },
  { id: 'id3', value: 'TODO3' },
];
```

I want to get type **'TODO1' | 'TODO2' | 'TODO3';**

```
const items = [...] as const;

type Type = typeof items[number]['value'];
```

I could get a type by const assertion. But this case, I lost my items type..

Comment: I don't think you should need the Item type at all - TS will infer it properly. There shouldn't be any issues having a narrow type when a wide one is accepted too. Remove `: Readonly<Item>[]` and use `as const`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define the array `as const` initially, then assign it to `items` later:

```
const itemsInitial = [
  { id: 'id1', value: 'TODO1' } as const,
  { id: 'id2', value: 'TODO2' } as const,
  { id: 'id3', value: 'TODO3' } as const,
];
type Type = typeof itemsInitial[number]['value'];
const items: Readonly<Item>[] = itemsInitial;
```

But you may not need the Item type at all - I don't see a need for it yet, or a need for the `Readonly<Item>[]` type, given the code in the question.